# Converting timestamp to epoch in snowflake

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unix-timestamp

I have timestamp in following format: "2022-03-08 17:11:59.901" , I want to convert them to UNIX/Epoch format up to milliseconds, somehow it only delivers till seconds part.
Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: can you please share what have you already tried? maybe something like `date_part(epoch_millisecond, your_timrstamp)` work?  
you can look at the examples at the bottom of this doc page: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_part.html

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')

Answer (score 4):

If you have a string timestamp and you want to convert to EPOCH:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2022-03-08 17:11:59.901') as ts,
       date_part(EPOCH_MICROSECOND ,ts)
```